# Comma placement conjunctions

Tags: grammar, conjunctions

Please Help! My question was not answered on ELL, and I'm studying for the ACT. I don't understand the answer to this question.

> Scientists did not find it problematic to explain the physical world with nonphysical phenomenon in seventeenth-century England. Though Bacon did.
>
> A) No Change
>
> B) England, but Bacon did.
>
> C) England; Bacon did.
>
> D) England like Bacon.

The correct answer is B, but I chose D.

I thought a comma was necessary between two independent clauses and a coordinating conjunction. However, "Bacon did" isn't a complete thought.

Comment: "but Bacon **"did"** = **Bacon found it**  _"problematic to explain the physical world with nonphysical phenomenon in seventeenth-century England"_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your sample sentence is an example of [ellipsis](https://www.dailywritingtips.com/a-guide-to-elliptical-constructions/) where certain words are left out in order to avoid repetitions.

The long form would be:

> Scientists did not find it problematic to explain the physical world
>   with nonphysical phenomenon in seventeenth-century England, but
>   Bacon did find it problematic.

To decide whether you need a comma before 'but' it is useful to consider what follows it. If the phrase has a subject and a verb, as in your case, insert a comma. If not, leave it out.